# Can I connect the ground pin of multiple switches in serial and then to the arduino ground

Tags: arduino

I've got multiple switches (buttons/toggles etc) and have connected the ground pin of each in serial#  and then the last one to the arduino ground.

Seems to work - but sometimes get unreliable behavior when one of the switches is closed.

Can the above be done - or do i have to connect the ground pin of each switch to a common ground bus.

Thanks.

Comment: A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: think of the ground pins of the switches as fence posts ... they are all driven into the same ground no matter where they are placed